# "Not an Answer" isn't blocked after flagging

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, not-an-answer

I have noticed this for some time, but never wanted to ask, until now, where I had to do some flagging.

As opposed to the Spam, Offensive and Moderator Attention flags, where after signaling, the site's interface prevents re-selection of those flags, signaling an answer as Not An Answer, besides not showing anything regarding to its status, after reselecting and flagging, a redundant messagebox appears stating that I already flagged the post for moderator attention.

Why does the Not an Answer flag work differently from the other flags mentioned, if it is not allowed to repeat the same flag? It seems like a slight design flaw, but I am looking for some reason that I might have missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior has been positively identified as a bug and will be fixed in the next build. See my [Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285272/2615940) about it.

Developer's reply is [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285280/2615940).